# GeSHi single like link

Tags: php, geshi

Is it possible to instruct GeSHi (http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) to generate link to single line. For example if I show highlighted code on 'example.com/my-code' URL, I would like to be able to have link like: 'example.com/my-mode#line-69' or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the docs: http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#adding-ids-to-each-line

So you have to do

```
$geshi->enable_ids(true);
```

And then all the lines will have ids which you can link to.

Comment: Uf, it is not really the happiest solution but I managed to work something out with JavaScript...